# Facebook and Twitter API help for Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

Im trying to implement Facebook and twitter into my app, anyone link a place with a good step by step for each.

I have tried several on various sites and youtube, and all have made my app crash. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: To add, im trying to make it so users can update there twitter and facebook status from my app.

Comment: Have you tried their documentation? Both have tutorials, sample code, and more information on their developer sites.

Comment: For twitter look at the dev.twitter.com where you can get the built-in libs. Also goto developers.facebook.com. Have you gone through the manuals? Which part are you facing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

One place to start might be using ShareKit:

http://www.getsharekit.com/

That bundles together a lot of social platform updates in something easy to integrate.  I think you can customize it beyond what is there.

Don't forget you'll need application ID's for each service you intend to link to - you need to create a twitter and Facebook app account.

Answer (score 1):

For twitter I use cocoa built in

```
  twitter.h
```

for iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

USE MGTwitter Engine to use twitter api in iphone.and PlainOauth library..It can be downloaded from githubsite..

Answer (score 0):

Definetely: 
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ 
- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios